# Netflix not working after Firefox upgrade

Tags: firefox, netflix, moonlight

I use `Firefox` with an addon to access `silverlight` contents. After upgrading I can't make it work again to watch Netflix.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use Googe-Chrome for Netflix?

Comment: Download and install Firefox ESR edition. [https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/)

Answer (score 3):

Mozilla Firefox no longer supports silverlight as of version 52.  The company states that this is for security reasons. See a statement on their support page [here.](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Problems-with-add-ons-plugins-or/tkb-p/Problems-Add-Ons-Plugins)